# Wordpress 3.0 embedded images

Tags: images

Wordpress 3.0 and newer does not allow you to remove the links placed on images without manually striping it withing the html.  Any idea how to do that by default?

Answer (score 4):

You actually can, there's a field on the upload image named "Link URL" which you can leave blank or just click the "None" button when you upload or edit an image in a post. Is this what you mean?

[image]

Comment: Works. Also verified, this indeed produces no anchor-tag (not just an empty one). Additionally have a look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18044/disable-image-attachment-links#answer-39906