# Disable image attachment links

Tags: wp-admin, images, attachments, links, uploads

Is there a way to disable image attachment links trought a filter in functions.php or something ? I know it's possible to do it manually when you add an image to a post but I want to disable this functionality by default.

**UPDATE**

What I want to do is set the "Link URL" option to "none" and remove / hide it from the upload attachement screen.

[image]

Is there a solution to hook into the "media-upload" "pop-in" ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: What theme do you use?

Comment: I use a custom theme that I created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anybody is interested in do the trick, my solution is this:

```
function remove_media_link( $form_fields, $post ) {

        unset( $form_fields['url'] );

              return $form_fields;

}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'remove_media_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 11):

Go to-> http://yourblog.com/wp-admin/options.php

Search for: image_default_link_type

Change Value to: none (available options are `none`, `file` [links to the file itself], `post` [links to the post the image is related to], `attachment` [links to the attachment page with the image on it])

or set it in your functions.php via (same options available as mentioned above)

```
update_option( 'image_default_link_type', 'none' );
```

Comment: This is great, i'm sure most people don't know of this `image_default_link_type` setting

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin to solve this called "[Remove Link URL](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-link-url/)" and it removes the link by default, still allowing it to be added in if you click the button. I believe this fixes the problem you're describing  :)

[screenshot-1.png?r=494378 http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/56/screenshot1vk.png](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-link-url/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to edit the loop-attachment.php in your theme, specifically lines 50-61:

```
if ( wp_attachment_is_image() ) {
                                echo ' <span class="meta-sep">|</span> ';
                                $metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
                                printf( __( 'Full size is %s pixels', 'twentyten' ),
                                    sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s &times; %4$s</a>',
                                        wp_get_attachment_url(),
                                        esc_attr( __( 'Link to full-size image', 'twentyten' ) ),
                                        $metadata['width'],
                                        $metadata['height']
                                    )
                                );
                            }
```

Pretty sure commenting out this whole block will achieve what you want. Haven't tested it myself though.

Comment: I use a custom theme which doesn't have loop-attachment.php in it.

Comment: ok. that complicates things. if you want to go down this route I would suggest you look in the main loop of the twenty-ten theme and see where the loop-attachment.php fits in, and try and import it over. Otherwise you could look for instances of `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` in your theme to see where your theme is attaching the image links.

Answer (score 1):

In functions.php or likewise file:

```
  update_option('image_default_link_type','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic php function that you would need to insert into your theme's functions.php file:

```
<?php
function lose_attachment($content){
return preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)\/attachment\/(.*?)"/i', '<a$1href="$2"', $content);
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'lose_attachment',2);
?>
```

This will remove the 'attachment/name-of-image-file' part from the URL making it link to the post's permalink itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but it doesn't seem to work. I also updated my question because removing 'attachment/name-of-image-file' is not exactly what I need.