# How can I change the default image behavior?

Tags: media, blog, options, customization

I would like to set the images in my blog to default to the large size, and clicking on them will perform the "Media Link" option. I could set this up every time I include an image in my blog, but I'm not confident I'll remember every image I have. How can I set Wordpress to use by default images that clicking on them will do the Media link option?

I'm running Wordpress 4.8, if it matters, hosted by HostGator.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269670/how-to-default-all-users-to-no-link-for-attachments - you'd just need to customize to use a link, as this answer removes all links.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't seem to save the options. But that's probably a different issue.